# Installation issue Node Red on my local. node-red Command not found

Tags: node.js, node-red

```
sudo npm install -g npm@2.x
/Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/lib
└── npm@2.15.12

MacBook-Pro-2:~ Beetel$ sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
npm WARN deprecated i18next-client@1.10.3: you can use npm install i18next from version 2.0.0
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/bin/node-red -> /Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
/Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/bin/node-red-pi -> /Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/node-red/bin/node-red-pi
/Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/lib
└── node-red@0.16.2

MacBook-Pro-2:~ Beetel$ node-red
-bash: node-red: command not found
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Is `/Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/bin` as that is where the executable was placed according to the output from npm

if not you can either add it to your path or run:

```
~ /Users/Beetel/.npm-packages/bin/node-red
```